# Awk argument too long when merging csv files

Tags: bash, csv, awk, merge

I have more than 10000 csv files in a folder and I'm trying to merge them by line using awk but if I run this command:
`printf '%s\n' *.csv | xargs cat | awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' *.csv > master.csv`
I get the following errors:
*/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long* and *printf: write error: Broken pipe*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `printf` and `xargs` parts, you are sending the *contents* of the csv files into awk, but you also provide the filenames to awk. Pick one or the other: I'd suggest:

```
{ printf '%s\n' *.csv | xargs awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}'; } > master.csv
```

Comment: That would fail if any file name contained spaces, you need `printf '%s\n' *.csv | xargs -d '\n' awk ...` or even better (so it'll even work for file names that contain newlines) `printf '%s\0' *.csv | xargs -d '\0' awk ...`. Having said that - the command as a whole wont work since the OP appears to be trying to skip the first line of every file except the first and that command will pass the file names to awk in batches so multiple "first line"s will be printed.

Comment: `head -n +1 whatever.csv; printf '%s\n' *.csv | xargs awk 'FNR>1'` would do the job if you can pick 1 of the CSVs to run `head` on to get that 1 first line.

Comment: If there are too many file names in the directory, xargs will invoke awk a second time causing the header line to be printed again.

Answer (score 2):

If your file names don't contain newlines then you could do:

```
printf '%s\n' *.csv | awk 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next} !c++ || FNR>1' -
```

or if they can contain newlines then:

```
printf '%s\0' *.csv | awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next} !c++ || FNR>1' RS='\0' - RS='\n'
```

i.e. have awk read the list of CSV file names as input rather than the shell passing it to awk as arguments. That would work even if you had millions of CSV files.

For example, given this input:

```
$ head -n +50 file*.csv
==> file1.csv <==
Number
1
2

==> file2.csv <==
Number
10
11
12
```

the above would produce this output:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *.csv | awk 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next} !c++ || FNR>1' -
Number
1
2
10
11
12
```